# How to detect Find My iPhone program xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How to use xcode 7.1 to make an app that will detect a status of the app "Find My iPhone" for iOS8 and iOS9. please help me

Comment: Could you rephrase this? I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: @Chris They want you to tell them how to use xchode 7.1 to make an app that will detect a status of the app "Find My iPhone" for iOS8 and iOS9. It should be flagged as what it is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (public) API to retrieve this information.